# Facebook connect Graph API Batch request parameters error

Tags: iphone, facebook, fbconnect

I'm using [Batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/batch/) in iOS FB connect app,
and I want for example events starting from today, limit 3

```
me/events?since=today
```

but it gives me events earlier than today and how can I add more parameters? with '&'?
it's not working exactly like in the graph api...

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work like as follow. Are you getting any error?

https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?limit=3&since=yesterday